# Lenovo onekey and reboot stuck in GRUB

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, grub, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo g50-45 with onekey recovery with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I dual booted with Ubuntu. Then I uninstalled Ubuntu. then tried to reinstall with USB using onekey. I got this screen:

```
    GNU GRUB ver2.02 .....ect.
    Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, .....ect.
    grub>
```

So, I did "ls" and got the following:

```
    grub> ls
    (hd0) (hd0,gpt7) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

All the others returned "Filesystem is unknown"

Only

```
grub> ls (hd0,3)
grub> ls (hd0,2)
```

returned "Filesystem is fat"

So, I looked at the files in these two partitions

```
grub> ls (hd0,2)/
```

returned:

```
efi/ boot/
```

Then I looked at other partition:

```
grub> ls (hd0,3)/
```

It returned:

```
bootmgr bootmgr.efi Version.txt Boot/ efi/ OneKey/ System Volume Information/
```

So obviously, the (hd0,3) partition is the Lenovo partition. and (hd0,2) is most probably windows.

My question is:

What steps do I take from here to get back into normal booting?

How do I get back to booting into Windows?

After that How do I go about installing Ubuntu? (by usb through onekey)

Any help is appreciated!

I am freaking out right now! THANKS!

****EDIT: more ls*****

I did:

```
    grub> ls (hd0,2)/boot/
```

I got:

```
   ./ ../ boot.sdi
```

Also did:

```
    grub> ls (hd0,2)/efi/
    ./ ../ Microsoft /Boot ubuntu/
    grub> ls (hd0,2)/efi/Microsoft/
    ./ ../ Boot/
    grub> ls (hd0,2)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/
    ./ ../ bg-BG/ bootmgr.efi memtest.efi boot.stl bootmgfw.efi bootstat.dat Fonts/    
    Resources/ BCD.LOG1 BCD.LOG2 bcd bcd. log
```

I don't know what to do!

****EDIT: I just need kernel!!**** One more thing I tried was:

```
    grub>set root=(hd0,2)
    grub>boot
    error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

So, how would I load kernel? Remember I don't have Ubuntu anymore. Just Windows8.1 kernel. I just need to load kernel. How do I do this!!!???

****EDIT: Almost there****

I entered into GRUB2:

```
    grub>set root=(hd0,2)
    grub>chainloader (hd0,2)+1
    error: invalid EFI file path
    grub>boot
    error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Please I feel like I am very close. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the MBR (Master Boot Record) to be able to boot Windows 8.1 again.

[Here is a quick guide on how to do it](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-fix-windows-8-mbr-master-boot-record/)